# Kubernetes deployment strategy to wait for all replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I got one service with auto scaling which means it can have 2 pods or 4 pods running. My issue is that this service is a reactjs application with service-worker.

With my current deployment strategy it will create a new pod and kill one at a time, which causes issues when the clients gets alarmed that there is a new update & tries to fetch new assets from server & the loadbalancer forwards it to the old pods.

So basicly I am wondering if it's possible to change to a strategy that creates x pods & replaces them all at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Recreate` deployment strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy) to first kill all old pods and then create new ones.

Alternatively, if you're looking to first create a parallel set of new pods, reroute traffic to these new pods and then kill the old pods (i.e., a [blue/green deployment](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)), check [this guide](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/bluegreen-deployments-kubernetes).

Comment: No this will kill the pods before creating the new one. I want to spin up the same amount that I got running, after healthchecking that all 3 are up and running it should replace the amount that's running on the old version

Comment: Or am I wrong? "All existing Pods are killed before new ones are created "

Comment: Oh right, that's correct. So what you're looking for is more of a [blue/green deployment](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)? Kubernetes doesn't have built-in support for that but [this guide](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/bluegreen-deployments-kubernetes) should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

add the spec.strategy.type in your deployment.yaml manfest and set it to "Recreate"
this will kill all the existing pods before new ones are created.

```
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

The strategy you are using is the - RollingUpdate , which is the default if you dont specify any.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this approach though it is manual and meets your requirement.

Say, you are running version 1.0 ( with label version:1.0 ) in the cluster and you want to upgrade to version 2.0

1. Deploy version 2.0 with label version:2.0
2. Verify that pods are running and your version 2.0 app is running fine.
3. edit version 1.0 service selector to use label version:2.0
4. Delete version 1.0 deployment